# Can't show image with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image

I must say that i'm a real beginner in this so keep that in mind. I'm currently working on a local server here and my problem here is that i'm trying to add a picture to my php code and don't really know if the problem come from mysql or from the actual code.

in mysql it's a varchar of 200 and it's named: products_image

And my code look like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Releases</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    require 'database_connection.php';

    $select_query = "SELECT * FROM releases";

    $result = mysql_query($select_query);

    if ($result) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $products_name = $row['products_name'];
        $products_title = $row['products_title'];
        $products_description = $row['products_description'];
        $products_image = $row['products_image'];

    } else {
        die("Error locating user with ID {$user_id}");
    }
    echo"{$products_name} {$products_title} {$products_description} ";
    echo "<img src=\"$products_image.\">";  
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And when i look at my source code it show me this for the image part:

```
<img src="C:\wamp\www\chaosruralenew\images\kalsahnikovdreams.jpg.">
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a local path to the server filesystem.

You should save the path relative to your website robot.

```
chaosruralenew/images/kalsahnikovdreams.jpg
```

Comment: Absolute or relative path would not make a difference.

Comment: I have tried that before and it gives me a broken image and when i click on it it the path changes to:
   http://localhost/chaosruralenew/scripts/chaosruralenew/images/kalsahnikovdreams.jpg

Comment: The path he is using is only valid from the server. Any user in other computer will not have the image file there

Comment: prepend a slash /chaosruralenew/imag es/kalsahnikovdreams.jpg

Comment: Ateszki, you rule. Starting with a slash, it finally show up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an erroneous period:

```
echo "<img src=\"$products_image.\">";
                                ^
```

Few other notes on your code:

- Did you also intend to use a loop to iterate through your results?
- `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. Learn about [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.
- It's wise to use error handlers such as `mysql_error` after your function.
- Depending on your HTML type, `<img>` may require a trailing slash `<img ... />`

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use the `html` tags outside the `PHP` code, by the way try this I hope it will work

```
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['products_image']; ?>"/>
```

save the image name with `.jpg` or any other valid extension of image in data base and retrieve it and display the image.

In this situation you don't need to take care of the path for the images.  I tried this and it is working for me very well.