# How to display random image and text from MySQL Database with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, random

I'm trying to make this html page (display.html) display a random image submission and random text submission from my MySQL table labeled "submissions".

This is the current code for display.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MIXED MESSAGES</title>
</head>
 <?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $name=$_POST['name'];  
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("voiid") or die(mysql_error()) ;
 ?> 
<body>
<?php

  $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

  while($rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    echo $rand['name'];
    echo $rand['pic'];
  }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment the page displays the text correctly, but instead of displaying a random image it will display a random images file name I.E hello5650_707133731307_3064319_n.jpg. I would also like a break between the text and the image.

Both the text and photo fields are VARCHAR(200). Not sure if I should be using a different data type.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Try adding `<img src...` to your `echo $rand['pic'];` and as for your linebreak, use `echo $rand['name'] . "<br>";` etc.

Comment: order by rand() is all fun and games until you try to do this same thing on a large database. just keep that in mind if you ever do something traffic intensive.

Comment: In conjunction with my above-said comment, you may need to add `http://www.yoursite.com/images/` depending where your images are stored, if your files are not inside the same folder.

Comment: thank you - what would the full line of code look like?

Comment: <img src=http://www.yoursite.com/images/ ...
this leads to displaying every image in the database. what would I have to add after /images/...?

thank you! @Fred-ii-

Comment: Try `echo "<img src=\"http://www.yoursite.com/\" . $rand['pic'].\">" . "<br>";`

Comment: Your `LIMIT 1` shouldn't be showing you more than one image. Try `SELECT name, pic FROM submissions` instead of using `*`

Comment: Also, try using `if` instead of `while` as per [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15329902/1415724) which will give you a better idea on how to do this.

Comment: Figured it out. But it wont display .jpeg files. I need to find a way to automatically convert each upload to .jpg in MySQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410133/automatically-convert-all-jpeg-files-to-jpg-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

> $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT
>   1");
>
> while($rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
>       echo $rand['name'] . "
> ";  echo "http://www.site.org/images/".$rand['pic'] ."'> 
> ";   }